# Android speech turn off number recognition

Tags: java, android, nlp, speech-to-text

Can anyone tell me if there is a parameter to shutoff the nlp of the google number translation within the android speech API?

For example I'm referring to the spoken 'seventy five' vs '75' recognized by the speech api.  It is currently only a number.

I've been looking on [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/RecognizerIntent.html), but it doesn't look like it.

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no such parameter.